# Swiftui view crashing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm creating a scrollview with lots of paragraphs of text in a VStack. For a particular page, the view crashes, giving the error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16f86ffe0)

When I delete a few paragraphs of text from the scrollview, it works fine (but obviously some text is now missing). It seems to be related to the number of entries in the Vstack. Is there any way to work around this?

Thanks,

Some code is below:

```
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                   
                    Group {
                    
                    Spacer().frame(height: 30)

                    Text("blah blah...").italic().lineSpacing(8)
                    Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                    
            
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                        
                       Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                    }
                    
                    Group {
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                        
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                    }
                                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)

                    Group {
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                   
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                   
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                    }
                    Group {
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                    
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                    }
                    Group {
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                    
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                    }
                    Group {
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                        
                    
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                    }
                
                Group {
                        Text("blah blah...").lineSpacing(8)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                }
                    
            }
                NavButtons()
                    .onAppear{toggleNavButtonsOn(gamesettings: settings)}
            }
            
        }.padding()
    
    }
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. However, you did not include the code for `NavButtons()` so that can't be tested.

Comment: The NavButtons() code works fine, so you can ignore that bit.

Comment: Then the issue is not reproducible, Xcode 13.3.1, iOS 15.4

Comment: If I comment out just one of those "Groups" above, then the code works fine. It doesn't matter which Group is commented out either, it can be any one of them.

Comment: I only commented out `NavButtons` and the `.onAppear()`. The rest of the code works fine.

Comment: Note,in SwiftUI there is a limit of 10 views, including VStack etc... that a View can contain.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine - how do I overcome that here?

Comment: you could package some of the views into separate `var`, such as: 
    `var extraViews1: some View { VStack {  //...up to 10 views  }  }`, each will be counted as 1 view.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine : is it not what Group are used for ?

Comment: @Ptit Xav, yes of course you can also `nest` Groups within `Group`. But I  feel, it is more readable if there are separate views.

Comment: Have you got any thing particular in your settings var ? or doing some specific things in toggleNavButtonsOn ?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine - that sounds a good idea, I’ll give that a go this evening